# Excel VBA: Web scraping now IE11 is nearly obsolete

Tags: excel, windows, web-scraping, internet-explorer

I’ve been using an Excel 2019 VBA InternetExplorer object to login to websites and get data via Copy and Paste. This has been an uphill struggle and, taking to account that  IE11 is now all but obsolete, what is the way forward? Edge isn't supported in Excel for some reason. I don’t need anything complicated, just to be able to login to a website and download screens/tables of data. The options as I understand are:

- XMLHTTP – great for simple websites, but it seems to be very hard to login to websites?
- Selenium – not portable.
- Are MS going to replace IE with something else in VBA?

Are there any other ways for what must be required by millions of people?

Comment: WebDriver for Edge is Microsoft's recommendation for programmatic browser control of MS Edge. The IE COM object will not be updated to work with MS Edge.

Comment: I agree with Bender mentioned. In addition, you could also try to use [Edge IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) if you want to implement the same feature in IE. But I recommend that you should focus more on modern browsers rather than IE.

Comment: Moving to Edge or Chrome has to be good. But using WebDriver + Selenium doesn't give a portable spreadsheet. Is there another way? I don't think Edge's IE Mode will work with VBA's InternetExplorer objects. Surely lots of people need to do simple web scraping from Excel!?! Even Excel's Data->Web function is pretty much useless now (and still uses IE).

Comment: If this is the case, I don't think there may be any other way to do it. And as already mentioned, Microsoft recommends WebDriver for automation. Using other third-party tools may be possible, but there are certain risks.